# Laravel Query builder in many to many Relationship

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Let's consider that I have a model called `Sportman` and another one `Sport` who are linked via a `pivot` table : **many to many** relationship.

A sample code for their migrations.

```
# Sportmans migration
Schema::create('sportsmans', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('firstname');
    $table->string('lastname');
});

# Sports migration
Schema::create('sports', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('description');
});
```

Here is their relationship in models :

```
# Defining association in Sportsman model
public function sports(){
    return $this->belongsToMany( Sport::class, 'sportsman_has_sports', 'person_id', 'sport_id' );
}

# Defining association in Sports model
public function sportsman(){
    return $this->belongsToMany( Sportsman::class );
}
```

How can I using Laravel with Eloquent get the `sportsman` that play:

1. Only "Footbal"
2. *Box* or "Swimming"
3. **Both "Tennis and *Basket-ball***

Here is what I tried to do for question 2 :

```
Sportsman::with(['sports:person_id,id,name'->whereHas('sports', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('name', ['Box', 'Swimming'] );
});
```

Most difficult is the **question 3**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post was edited with my approach in answer to your question

Comment: What isn't working with your approach for question 2? What does "Either Tennis and Basketball" mean?

Comment: It works but as I said, it is more difficult for question 3. What I'm thinking about is to do it (*question 3*) programatically after calling the `get` method

Comment: Why are you asking about it when you already have a solution? What does "Either Tennis and Basketball" mean?

Comment: it's my bad, I should use "both". It was edited

Answer (score 2):

You put a subquery on whereHas function...

```
Sportsman::whereHas('sports', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('name', ['Box', 'Swimming'] );
})
->with('sports')
->get();
// Below is your last question
Sportsman::where(function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('sports', function ($subquery) {
        $subquery->where('name', 'Tennis');
    });
    $query->whereHas('sports', function ($subquery) {
        $subquery->where('name', 'Basket-ball');
    });
})
->with('sports')
->get();
```

Comment: It works but the problem with that is that it will execute a more complex/huge query because for each sports that will be existing in the request, it will add an extra join. So don't you think it will be better to filter result (*as simple collection*) after basic query execution?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you that, because with time the data will grow, and you will bring unnecessary data to a collection, which will slow down you application.